# How can I work around the delays after Overlord mutation and Changeling spawn?

Tags: starcraft-2

There are 2 delays that really annoy me about Overlords/-seers.

- The mutation start from Overlord to Overseer. If I run a mutation and I don't wait at least 1/2s to give him a move order, the mutation gets cancelled.
- When I spawn a Changeling, I have to wait also at least 1/2s before I can select it.

Does someone have any workarounds to avoid loosing these delays, or are they here on purpose ?

Comment: Just wondering, if it could be caused by latenzy. Have you had any latenzy problems during your online play in StarCraft2? Give it a try in a game in offline mode.

Comment: I have no latency, I usually also see this behavior on streams. Sometimes I see progamers facing the issue.

Comment: what happens if you shift move him, does the move get canceled?

Comment: Good to know for the overloard mutation indeed.

Comment: @AtlasEU you forgot an `f´ there

Comment: *shift-move hehe

Answer (score 3):

You can use the queue to give the orders to the overseer to be able to move on to controlling another unit immediately.

Instead of "Overseer Morph", *wait*, "Overseer move", you would issue the commands "Overseer Morph", "Shift + Overseer move". That way the move command is queued after the morph and doesn't cancel it.

Unfortunately, I don't have an idea for the changeling as the unit is only created and thus cannot receive queued commands before it appears.